# Common fixed point for two functions

Tags: calculus

> Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ and $0 \leq g(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$, which satisfy $f \circ g = g \circ f$. If $f(x)$ is not increasing, is it true that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common fixed point?

If $f(x)$ is increasing, we use the following argument.

Suppose $f(x) > x$. Then since $f(x)$ is increasing, $f(f(x)) > f(x)$, $f(f(f(x))) > f(f(x))$, etc. Thus the sequence $x, f(x), f(f(x)),\ldots$ is increasing and bounded by $1$ and so it has a limit. The proof when $x < f(x)$ is similar.

Now we note that there is some $m$ with $g(m) = m$. Then according to the above, the sequence $f^k(m)$ has a limit $l$, which is a fixed point for $f(x)$. Moreover, $$f^k(m) = f^k(g(m)) = g(f^k(m))$$ since $f \circ g = g \circ g$. Then we have $$l = \lim_{k \to \infty} f^k(m) = \lim_{k \to \infty} g(f^k(m)) = g(\lim_{k \to \infty} f^k(m)) = g(l).$$

But what if $f(x)$ is not increasing? Does the limit point necessarily still exist?

Comment: can you prove there is a point $x$ with $f(x)=g(x) $?

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample to the conjecture, that two commuting selfmaps of $[0,1]$ must have a common fixed point, was given by [William M. Boyce, Commuting functions with no common fixed point, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 127 (1969), 77-82](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-137-00/S0002-9947-1969-0236331-5/S0002-9947-1969-0236331-5.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x)=x$, then $g(x)=g(f(x))=f(g(x))$, so $g(x)$ is also a fixed point for $f$.

Notice that since $f$ is non-increasing $f-x$ is a strictly decreasing function, hence $f$ has exactly one fixed point.

Let $x$ be that fixed point, then $g(x)$ is also a fixed point of $f$, since there is only one we have $g(x)=x$. So $x$ is the common fixed point.

Comment: What do you think the OP meant by "$f(x)$ is not increasing"? Did he mean that $f(x)$ is a "non-increasing" (i.e. nonstrictly decreasing) function? Or did he mean the negation of "$f(x)$ is an increasing function"?

Comment: I don't know, but both cases are covered with our solutions.

Answer (score -1):

[Edit](I see $f$ has to be positive, take the f i gave and let $F=-f$, it all still works). No, but the best way to tackle the problem is through a counterexample. Try taking $g$ to be the identity, and $f(x)$ to be $-x$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $x-1$ on $[1/2,1]$. $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=f(x)$.  1 is a fixed point of $g$, in fact the only one. But what happens with $f^k(1)$?

Comment: Doesn't the identity fix every point?

Comment: My mistake I meant to write $g(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and then $f(g(x))=f(0)=0$ whereas $g(f(x))=0$.

Comment: that won't work either, because $g(f(x))$ is the constant $0$ function, while $f(g(x))$ is the constant function which sends everything to $f(0)$. and if they are equal then $0$ is a common fixed point.

Comment: Seeing that-- my mistake; i'm off to dinner but will think on it a little more and get back.

Comment: enjoy :) ${}{}{}$